# How do I stop my speaker from POPPING when I plug and unplug my headphones?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, ubuntu-studio

my laptop speakers pop very loudly every time I plug in or unplug my headphones. I followed the suggested advice of disabling `Auto-Mute Mode` in alsamixer, and voila, no more popping. HOWEVER, now I can hear audio coming from both my speakers *and* my headphones. This might not come as a surprise for some, but toggling enabled and disabled for the Auto-Mute Mode causes popping as well.

I'm running Ubuntu Studio 14.04 dual-booted with Windows 8 on a Lenovo y410p laptop. This problem only occurs in Ubuntu.

If helpful, here's output from `aplay -l`:

```
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ID 282 Analog [ID 282 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ID 282 Digital [ID 282 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds more like a hardware issue.

Comment: Could it still be a hardware issue if the same doesn't happen in Windows 8 @Virusboy ? I'll edit to include that I've dual-booted and it only happens in Ubuntu Studio.

Comment: Does this same behaviour occur when on battery power and on mains power?  Might sound like a silly question, but the sound card might have power saving modes that are causing issues.

Comment: @neon_overload: I'm actually always on mains power. (My battery died a long time ago...and has been removed.)